# Sorting gameobjects using sorting algorithms

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine, swap

I want to sort 5 spheres in Unity by using sorting algorithms. They will swap places in sorted order after I click sort button. I manage to create a list for gameobjects but as I understand it is only sorting the list then do nothing. How to create such script that I want? It will swap objects by gameobject name. [The Envrioment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZwZO.png),
 the code that I made so far;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace Assets
{

    class Gameobjects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Button s_YourButton;
        [SerializeField]
        private GameObject[] deck;

        public List<GameObject> instanciatedObjects;

        void Start()
        {
            Button btn = s_YourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            //Calls the TaskOnClick method when you click the Button
            btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);

        }

        void TaskOnClick()
        {
            Fill();
            instanciatedObjects = instanciatedObjects.OrderBy(Sphere => Sphere.name).ToList();
        }

        public void Fill()
        {
            instanciatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
            {
                instanciatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(deck[i]) as GameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea is welcome for me to do futher research, I am new to Unity.

Comment: Please show what the names look like. Maybe a screenshot of the Hierarchy tab?

Comment: Sphere, Sphere (1), Sphere (2), Sphere (3), Sphere (4) as you can see at [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZwZO.png).

Comment: What should happen after the sorting the objects in the List? I don't know what you expect next

Comment: After sorting I want to change the place of the spheres with sorted ones, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRRTA.png) After I randomize I want them to be sorted like this after I use sort button. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PESav.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can do is store a list of Vector3 of the old one. basicly `List.Add(spawnedObject.transform.position);` inside the for loop in `Fill()`.

Then after you sorted them, you loop the `instanciatedObjects` and set them in the same order as the Vector3 list.

```
List<Vector3> vectorList = new List<Vector3>();
void TaskOnClick()
{
    Fill();
    instantiatedObjects = instantiatedObjects.OrderBy(Sphere => Sphere.name).ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < instanciatedObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        instantiatedObjects[i].transform.position = vectorList[i];
    }
}

public void Fill()
{
    vectorList.Clear();
    instantiatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject spawnedObject = Instantiate(deck[i]) as GameObject;
        instantiatedObjects.Add(spawnedObject);
        vectorList.Add(spawnedObject.transform.position);
    }
}
```

btw, a typo in your code: `instanciatedObjects` should be `instantiatedObjects`

Comment: +1. tl;dr: You sort the list by object name, then apply the sorted positions on the unsorted object-list. Now the objects apper in the sorted order.

Comment: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy0mI.png) This is the result, It may be caused because of the name of spheres may be?

Comment: It is kind of difficult to see which object is which, and which object spawns where. Currently this code just sorts by the position of where the object is initially spawned.

Comment: I don't know why but I think there is an additional balls that stay in second and third position so they seem merged so it is not possible to see, I think the older balls needs to be destoryed after sorting the spawned ones but still there is something wrong with order. After sorting it sorts the unsorted ones by 1 # # 5 2. :D [Closer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdXwm.png)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile the script while running, which isnt reccomended, can you also try to check if the order of the list and the position is correct when you are starting? And please only one set of objects.

Comment: Here at [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSikH.png) it is wrongly sorted  Here [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMMKC.png)  after I change Sphere names to make them to sorted right it doesnt even sort. First I click randomize to make the order like 5 3 2 4 1 then I try to sort.

Comment: It does not even sort, cause it is already sorted. Obviously the names of the spheres does not even correspond to the numbers in the deck.

Sphere (1) = 5
Sphere (2) = 3
Sphere (3) = 2
Sphere (4) = 4
Sphere (5) = 1

Comment: It seems you are trying to randomize the order with either the sprite, can you try randomizing the order of the list too, cause then you can sort.

Comment: I manage to do by changing the order of the objects at sorting as you mentioned and I destroyed the objects after ordering so there will be only clones; [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FajUM.png) This is fine but I have to use standart sorting algorithms for sorting the list and my supervisor said I need to make a delay for process of swapping elements two by two so the sorting process is visible that is the real issue I have now. :D Randomizing here; [Randomize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf1Mi.png)

Comment: I will create a different question for it later and I may @ you if you are interested and want to help. :)